# Keep portion of hero image background for sticky nav

Tags: html, css, background, nav, sticky

I have a page with a hero image, and the nav slides in from the top, logo top left and menu links top right, over the top of the hero image. What I want to achieve is when I scroll down the page, the nav is sticky, which is easy enough, but also keeps the portion of the hero image it's over the top of, as the sticky nav background. I know I could just get the height of the nav, crop that from the hero image and make it the background for the nav, but thought there might be an easier way to do it dynamically so it does it with whatever hero image is used etc.

Any ideas? Can't seem to find much help on this after Googling and looking on here, they're all just asking about and showing how to make a nav sticky, which is the easy part, keeping the hero image as the sticky nav background is another story...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might complement your post with some code.

Comment: please, provide some code of your work.

Comment: What code would you like me to post? I haven't made it yet. I want to make it. The code I currently have is irrelevant. It literally does what I described in my post. I'm after the method to use, CSS, JS, how would you guys go about it etc.